# Using CMD on Windows to remove a specific substring from a directory of files

Tags: windows, cmd, substring

I frequently use a free online lossless file compressor to save space on my disk and make transferring and pushing repos easier. My main problem with the compressor is it appends "-min" to the end of every filename. For various reasons, I want to replace the original files by overwriting them; instead of deleting the old files and keeping the new files (with the "new" names).

For my PDF directory, I tried this:
FOR /R %f IN (*-min.pdf) DO REN "%f" *.pdf

And it seems to correctly find all the corresponding files, but their names remain the same. What am I doing incorrectly? Is there a single command that would be file-format-agnostic, so I wouldn't have to sub out the file extension for txt's, png's, etc?

I just need it to remove the -min from the end of each filename (before the file extension).

Comment: The FOR variable %f is assigned the whole file name, not the "*" matched part; so you are renaming the file with the same name. You have to do some string processing, wich is a rather tricky thing in Windows batch, and I don't think it can be done in a one line command. If %f is a file name the expression %~nf returns the name without extension; %s:0,-4% returns all but the last 4 characters of a string s, and so on. Search "windows batch string processing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `FOR /R %f IN (*-min.pdf) DO REN "%f" *.pdf`

For a one liner (at the cmd prompt) remove `echo` from the following.

```
cmd /v:on /c "for /R %f in (*-min.pdf) do @set "nx=%~nxf" & echo ren "%~ff" "!nx:-min.pdf=.pdf!""
```

The above can be easily changed to perform other string manipulations, *but* it is not technically foolproof, for example it will rename a file named `"a-min.pdf.b-min.pdf-c-min.pdf"` to `"a.pdf.b.pdf-c.pdf."`. If that is a concern in this case, then use the following, which is essentially the same as in @Mofi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643815/5538420).

```
cmd /v:on /c "for /R %f in (*-min.pdf) do @set "nn=%~nf" & echo ren "%~ff" "!nn:~0,-4!%~xf""
```

Comment: It isn't essentially the same as @Mofi's answer. `for /R` passes to the `do` as command soon as it gets its first result and continues to do so as it iterates. This means any changes to a file name in the `do` command could be cycled again into the running `for /R` command. Whilst in this case, as you're removing the `-min` substring, this won't affect anything, it's an important distinction to make; because Mofi's parenthesized command method is all processed before being passed to the `do` portion. As this is tagged `cmd` and not `batch-file` however yours would be more correct in this case.

Comment: @Compo Good points. I used `for /R` to keep it close to OP's attempt and, indeed, the loop is restricted to `*-min.pdf` so that renamed files don't match the wildcard. One other difference is that the loop written this way works fine with filenames with international characters outside the active codepage.

Answer (score 1):

The task can be done with a batch file with following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*-min.*" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set "FullFileName=%%I"
    set "FileNameOnly=%%~nI"
    set "FileExtension=%%~xI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if /I "!FileNameOnly:~-4!" == "-min" ren "!FullFileName!" "!FileNameOnly:~0,-4!!FileExtension!"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The twice used negative value `-4` must match with the length of the string to remove from the end of the file name left to the file extension. The string `-min` has a length of four characters which is the reason for using here twice `-4`.

The command **DIR** executed by a separate command process started by **FOR** in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments outputs also file names like `Test-File!-min.x.pdf` with full path. For that reason the **IF** condition makes sure to rename only files of which file name really ends case-insensitive with the string `-min` like `Test-File!-MIN.pdf`.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The code works even for files of which fully qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) contains one or more exclamation marks because of [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled only for the command line which finally renames a file.

The file renaming task can be done faster with permanently enabled delayed variable expansion as long as no file contains anywhere one or more `!` in its fully qualified file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*-min.*" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileNameOnly=%%~nI"
    if /I "!FileNameOnly:~-4!" == "-min" ren "%%I" "!FileNameOnly:~0,-4!%%~xI"
)
endlocal
```

This code does not work for renaming `Test-File!-MIN.pdf` to `Test-File!.pdf` because of `!` in file name.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of the batch file which always ends with a backslash. It is concatenated with the wildcard pattern `*-min.*` for that reason without an additional backslash. `%~dp0` can be removed to run **DIR** on current directory and all its subdirectories instead of batch file directory and all its subdirectories.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.